# Student t-distribution: why the dash [sic, EA; hyphen]

Tags: dashes

In statistics, the *t*-distribution is important. It is an approximation to the normal distribution. Of course we don't say "normal-distribution" (with the dash).

Well then, what exactly is the grammatical justification for calling it

> *t*-distribution

as opposed to just

> *t* distribution

?

Or to put it another way, is there a good name for *the practice of using a dash in this kind of context*?

Comment: single letters alone are considered ugly? (except for 'I' and 'a' (unless those are just the letters and not the single-letter words))

Comment: These types of things are jargon of the field, they're often ideosyncratic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hyphen — not a dash — commonly joins an initial single letter/digit to form a compound word [[Public Works and Government Services_Canada ... BtB Translation Bureau](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_h&page=9-ejssVlOSeQ.html)].

Left to its own devices, general usage will capitalize:

> A-side, B-side, T-shirt, A-shirt, O-level, X-ray

Otherwise, various commercial or scientific fields set their own conventions. There is no particular reason why, for instance, it's *t*-distribution but T-cell beyond the tendency in mathematics not to capitalize letters except in special circumstances. In other words, it’s E = mc<sup>2</sup> by community agreement and convention.

Many e-words such as *e-commerce, e-learning*, and especially *e-mail* are dropping their hyphens. I've also seen B movie both ways.