# N-times differentiable function should go with hyphen?

Tags: hyphenation, dashes

Suppose that I would like to say "Let f(x) be an N-times differentiable function."

Should it be "N-times" or "N times", and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Student t-distribution: why the dash](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/476899/student-t-distribution-why-the-dash) { 'hyphens: numerals and single letters
Hyphenate numerals or single letters and the words they modify: e-cigarette
e-commerce
e-learning
S-hook
T-shirt
U-turn
1,2-dimethylbutylene
2,4-D ...' [BtB Public Works ... Translation Bureau]

Comment: Thanks, but no. t-distribution refers to a compound thing, so there must be a hyphen. This is different with the question (or is it?).

Comment: Yes it does, within the remit of ELU. [n times] or [n-times] is a compound word with a letter as first element, as are 'T-shirt' and 'e-commerce'. If there is here (as DjinTonic's research shows) a very different bias, this is because of the mathematical preferences involved, and this question is better asked on Mathematics.SE. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/two-time) gives the hyphenated spelling of the adjective _two-time_: [adj] 
[attributive] ... 
‘a two-time winner of the event’. (Though I'm sure the open compound is also used.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've edited my answer. I believe *two-time* and *two times/two-times* behave differently. Few would disagree with the hyphen for *time.*

Comment: @DjinTonic Probably. 'Two-time' is on-topic (if answerable by basic research); 'n-times / n times' (prenominal) as used here is non-everyday English, I'd say maths-specific.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Even if *n times* is based on analogy with *four times champion of the world*?

Comment: @DjinTonic 'No hyphen seems to be much more common' seems to need 'in maths usages':  a Google search for "four times champion" rather than "four times differentiable" gives a less uneven distribution of hyphenated/open forms. Of course, it's hard to find an everyday adjective that 'n times' modifies sensibly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No hyphen** seems to be much more common in math, as this Google Books [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22N-times%20differentiable%20function%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01n0tj-3ELANYCq20Sf473iO8sPHQ%3A1628333964340&ei=jGcOYb6fFNPRtQbhmKmICA&oq=%22N-times%20differentiable%20function%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10359.32731.0.33135.14.14.0.0.0.0.110.1209.12j2.14.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.378...33i299k1j33i10i299k1j33i10k1.0.0viKMqiZkA0) for "N-times differentiable function" indicates, with six out of six  examples hyphenless. (Looking at more pages in the search I see one example with a hyphen and dozens without.) If I were writing this, my instinct would be to use a hyphen.

This may have to do with how we modify *times*:

> "...and will meet with n times as many ethereal particles , and will
> impinge upon each particle with **n times greater velocity"** [ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n%20times%20greater%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03YASLwtstAIf2i0oMiFQWrFqpzuA:1628334901577&ei=NWsOYdHfIondtQb324jQCQ&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiRzoib5J7yAhWJbs0KHfctApoQ8NMDegQIARBP&biw=1067&bih=621&dpr=1.25)

> ...the lifting force becomes **n times greater** than it was... [ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n%20times%20greater%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03YASLwtstAIf2i0oMiFQWrFqpzuA:1628334901577&ei=NWsOYdHfIondtQb324jQCQ&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiRzoib5J7yAhWJbs0KHfctApoQ8NMDegQIARBP&biw=1067&bih=621&dpr=1.25)

I think we agree that a hyphen is needed for *a six-time Olympic champion*.

However,

> ... making her a four **times** champion of the world. [ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22four%20times%20champion&biw=1067&bih=621&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02ZAKKZ7ZwtFootADQRCU7PNJhFog%3A1628336880794&ei=8HIOYfz8L9DWtAautYfoDg&oq=%22four%20times%20champion&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11656.12089.0.12416.5.5.0.0.0.0.172.618.2j3.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.qusJ99KB7mI) (1918)

and

> ...he was not destined to join Harry Vardon and Braid as four-**times**
> champion  [ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22four%20times%20champion&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01keVOo4W90OzD-gPDEpR0aBXwd6Q:1628336894038&ei=_nIOYcV7mM21Br3butAB&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjF8pHR657yAhWYZs0KHb2tDhoQ8NMDegQIARBP&biw=1067&bih=621&dpr=1.25) (1908)

Comment: Yes, I feel it more natural to use hyphen, though I don't why the literature go without hyphen.

Comment: 1,2-dimethylbutylene is prescribed. And Lexico gives the hyphenated spelling of the adjective two-time: [adj] [attributive] Denoting someone who has done or experienced something twice. ‘a two-time winner of the event’. This question is thus obviously about non-quotidian English usage; this belongs on Mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as

> *n*–times differentiable function

### Why the en-dash?

Because *n* and *times* are compound adjectives describing *function*. It makes no sense to say

> ? n function

or

> ? times function;

both the *n* and the *times* must be modifying *function* together to make sense.

Here are some helpful citations:

[Student t-distribution: why the dash [sic, EA; hyphen]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/476899/student-t-distribution-why-the-dash)

[When should com­pound words be writ­ten as one word, with hy­phens, or with spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spac/34766#34766)

### Why is *n* lowercase?

When *n* refers to an arbitrary integer in writing about mathematics, it is written in lowercase and (usually) is italicized (and put into a math font).

Comment: Dashes are rarely used in compounds (and there's no possibility of one here). Some use the en-dash to form larger compounds involving shorter open or hyphenated compounds [[Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/en-dash/)].

Comment: You are correct. I have changed my answer to use en-dash.